# Fast PC slow Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia

I have a fast PC, I built myself with the following specs:

- i7 3770k
- 5 SSD's
- GTX 970
- Corsair AX1200i
- 8GB RAM
- 3 x 27inch 2560 x 1440

I installed Ubuntu Studio and had no issues, it ran smoothly, but I wanted the side dock and didn't really like the way it was set up, so I installed Ubuntu 14.04.

It seems that it is running slower than it should, if I go to the search bar I can see it slowly show up and typing has a little bit of a delay..

Two of my monitors are working only and one is only stuck in 1080p with the other one in 1440p. I am also having issues installing my drivers, I do the entire `sudo` command setup and it keeps installing a nouveau driver, which when I load up Nvidia X server I cannot configure my monitors or anything...

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: could be nvidia issue, but my first guess would be that `unity` , default graphics interface in Ubuntu, is a bit taxing for your machine, and switching to Gnome shell would be a reasonable suggestion

Comment: Sooo... I figured out what the issue was, installed the drivers a certain way, restarted Ubuntu and the problem was solved.. Fyi f you are having issues with a fast pc running slow on your ubuntu, look up all ways to install GPU drivers and go from there

Thanks... Ubuntu is running lightning fast :)

Comment: Congrats on solving the issue. Can you please post it as an answer so that other people who stumble upon your question may see what has helped you ? Thanks

Comment: Sorry about that.. And thanks to whomever for editing it for me.. I was exhausted and didn't pay attention to my grammar, that's my fault. :(

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I'm new to the site..

The problem was fixed by trying a few different methods of installing the Nvidia Drivers, once I got that done and restarted all was well.

Used the terminal and installed 335.06 drivers, anyone having similar issues, hope this helps.. Sometimes all you need to do, is restart..